# Determine context of framework currently running in

Tags: .net-standard

I have a .net standard library that will be called from either a .net framework 4.x program or a .net core program.  When the code is executing a method in the .net standard library I would like to check to see the context of the framework it was called from.  More specific : if called from within 4.x I want to ensure that the 4.x set the value of a static variable in the standard library, whereas when called from core I want to ensure it wasn't set.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly handle that with an [`#if` preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if).  There is the list of target framework's names in the article, so you could do something akin to

```
#if NET48 || NET472 || ...
    staticVariable = "SomeStaticValue";
#endif
```

As a small suggestion, though, if it's possible for you to set that variable in the program that's using it, that'd likely be easier.  It could then be passed into the library and used if needed.